# Laravel and running through a batch of results

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm having a big head ache with Laravel's `chunk` and `each` functions for breaking up result sets.

I have a table, that has a column `processed` with a value of `0`. If I run the following code, it goes through all 13002 records.

```
Record::where(['processed' => 0])->each(function ($record) { 
    Listing::saveRecord($record);
}, 500);
```

This code will run through all 13002 records. However, if I add in some code to mark a record as processed, things go horribly pear shaped.

```
Record::where(['processed' => 0])->each(function ($record) { 
    $listing_id = Listing::saveRecord($record);

    $record->listing_id = $listing_id;
    $record->processed = 1;
    $record->save();
}, 500);
```

When this code runs, only 6002 records are processed.

From my understand of things, that on each iteration of of the `chunk` (`each` runs through `chunk`), that it's executing a new statement.

I've come from using Yii2 and I'm mostly happy with the move, except for this hiccup, which has me pulling my hair out. Yii2 has similar functions (`each` and `batch`), but they seem to use result sets and pointers, so even if you update the table while you're processing your results, it doesn't effect your result set.

Is there actually a better way to do this in Laravel?

Comment: Why not just do an actual foreach loop? Something along `$records = Record::where('processed', false)->get();` and then `foreach ($records as $record)`? By the way, you are using Eloquent models, right? If so, your model name should be singular (ie. `Record` instead of `Records`).

Comment: Because I don't want to load all the records into memory, because I get a memory error. The whole point of `each` and `chunk` is so that you don't have to load all the results in memory, so you can iterate through smaller "chunks" of the result set to process, so you're using less memory. As for the record class name, you're right, I made the change, but it's just example code.

Comment: I know this is an oldish question now, but why not store another flag that you do not select on for your processing e.g. `(bool) completed`? Then run something like `update listing set processed=true where completed=true;` after you have finished.

Comment: Hey @SynackSA What was your solution in the end?

Answer (score 11):

Try this

```
 Records::where('processed',0)->chunk(100, function($records){
    foreach($records as $record)
    {
      //  do your stuff... 
    }
 });
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries#chunking-results

Sorry about indentation, on my phone and that doesnt work apperently..

Comment: This is literally what the `each` function does. https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.2/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php#L418